# How to resolve 'Duplicate class' in nested dependency libraries

Tags: android, gradle

Let's say I have two third-party libraries which are implemented using gradle. Those libraries might have lots of other dependencies. And one of those dependencies have the same class.

For example:

```
com.x.somelib
L com.y.lib:1.2.3
  L com.android.somelib.someclass
com.q.anotherlib
L com.y.lib:1.3.2
  L com.android.somelib.someclass
```

So I get an error

```
Duplicate class com.android.somelib.someclass in com.y.lib:1.2.3 and com.y.lib:1.3.2
```

It happened after I added com.x.somelib dependency. But I do not know where the second one in. I have like 100 of different libraries used. Moreover, the second library might be a built-in library inside the game engine I use. So I'm not able to remove it without modifying the source code, which I do not want to.

So. What I've tried:

```
dependencies {
 implementation ('com.x.somelib') { // also tried 'com.y.lib:1.3.2'
  exclude module : 'com.android.somelib.someclass' // also tried 'exclude group'
 }
}
```

And this

```
configurations {
 all {
  resolutionStrategy {
   force 'com.y.lib:1.3.2'
  }
 }
}
```

None of these helped me.

I'm not really sure what to do and how do I remove duplicate classes, when I do not have access to one of the libraries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I did a mistake trying to exclude group, but specifing a class.

What I did to make it work is:

```
dependencies {
 implementation ('com.x.somelib') {
  exclude group : 'com.android.somelib' // Not com.android.somelib.someclass
 }
}
```

Here is an example with an error I had:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.17.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.15.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.1)
```

So I had to add

```
dependencies {
 implementation ('com.applovin.mediation:mytarget-adapter:5.15.5.0') {
  exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer'
 }
}
```